# How to update Description/Optional ID field of a Test Instance in QC 11 using QTP?

Tags: qtp, hp-quality-center

I want to update a specific field (description/Optional ID) of a test instance in QC using QTP. Below is waht I am curently doing:

1. Through QTP, by calling OTA API I am connecting to QC and pulling test instances into one of the test set in test lab (this code is working)
2. Now I want to update either description or Optional ID field of every pulled instance (I have all these things in excel)

PS: I am sorry but I cant put my piece of code here. I am stuck at adding that field value. I could reach till TSTestFactory but cant reach beyond that.

Please let me know if anyone has any clue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from code I use to update the status of TestSet tests.

```
  TSTestFactory tstf = (TSTestFactory)m_Connection.TSTestFactory;
  List tests = tstf.NewList("");

  foreach (TSTest test in tests)
  {
    test.Status = status;
    test.Post();
  }
```